# Highlighting and scrolling to a reference

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am writing some kind of a reading comprehension task, in which the page is built from two parts: on the left hand appears the text itself (say ~50 lines, so the containing div has a vertical scroll bar), on the left hand there are questions.

One of the common question types is "what does the word *bla* on the 4th paragraph relate to?"

What I want to do is this: when the user clicks the word *bla* on the question, the corresponding word in the text should be highlighted (like with `mark` tag) and the text itself should be automatically scrolled so the relevant paragraph gets to the top of the div (or at least becomes visible).

The app itself is built with angular but I first tried to construct a POC using plain HTML-JS-CSS files. My naïve solution currently has an `<a>` tag on the relevant question word, a class wrapping the relevant word in the text, a CSS rule for the highlighting and a JavaScript function to toggle the highlighting on/off. still haven't found a solution for the scrolling issue.

Is there anything in the html5 built-in goods, or maybe something ready-to-use in angular?

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track.

A fallback to pure HTML would just use an internal anchor

```
<a href="#question1">Question 1</a>

...

inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo
enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit <span id="question1">aspernatur</span> si architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo
enim ipsam voluptatem quia volup

...
```

You can then augment this with a basic script that attaches a listener to the questions container, intercepts the link click, and scrolls to the relevant parent element while marking the tagged word with an active class.

```js
//query the questions column
const questionsCol = document.getElementById('questions');

//attach a click listener to the retrieved column
questionsCol.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  // prevent the default event
  event.preventDefault();
  
  // retrieve the id of the question from the 'href' attribute of the link
  const questionId = event.target.getAttribute("href");
  // query the text column
  const textCol = document.getElementById('text');
  // find the relevant word using the question id
  const answerEl = textCol.querySelector(questionId);
  // scroll the text column to the top-offset of the answer word's parent paragraph
  textCol.scrollTop = answerEl.parentNode.offsetTop;
  
  // look for the last active answer word
  const lastActive = textCol.querySelector('.active-answer');
  // if found, remove the active class
  if (lastActive) lastActive.classList.remove('active-answer');
  // add the active class to the newly linked answer word
  answerEl.classList.add('active-answer');
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.column {
  position: relative;
  width: 45%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.active-answer {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="questions" class="column">
    <p class="question">What does <a href="#question2" class="reference">aspernatur</a> refer to in paragraph 2?</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p class="question">What does <a href="#question6">eligendi</a> refer to in paragraph 4?</p>
  </div>
  <div id="text" class="column">
    <h3>The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s</h3>
    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
      magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
      Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
    </p>
    <h3>Section 1.10.32 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", written by Cicero in 45 BC</h3>
    <p>"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem
      aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo
      enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit <span id="question2">aspernatur</span> aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui
      ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur,
      adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat
      voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut
      aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil
      molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"</p>
    <h3>1914 translation by H. Rackham</h3>
    <p>"But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I
      will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the
      truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is
      pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are
      extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it
      is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure.
      To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some
      advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no
      annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"</p>
    <h3>Section 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", written by Cicero in 45 BC</h3>
    <p>"At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque
      corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa
      qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita
      distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est <span id="question6">eligendi</span> optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime
      placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut
      officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non
      recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias
      consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat."</p>
    <h3>1914 translation by H. Rackham</h3>
    <p>"On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by
      the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee the pain and trouble that are
      bound to ensue; and equal blame belongs to those who fail in their duty through weakness of will, which is the
      same as saying through shrinking from toil and pain. These cases are perfectly simple and easy to distinguish. In
      a free hour, when our power of choice is untrammelled and when nothing prevents our being able to do what we like
      best, every pleasure is to be welcomed and every pain avoided. But in certain circumstances and owing to the
      claims of duty or the obligations of business it will frequently occur that pleasures have to be repudiated and
      annoyances accepted. The wise man therefore always holds in these matters to this principle of selection: he
      rejects pleasures to secure other greater pleasures, or else he endures pains to avoid worse pains."</p>
  </div>
</div>
```